# jquery first child syntax

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with this syntax?

```
var on_a = 0; // declared outside document ready

on_a = $("#sb_results > a:first");

$(on_a + " .sbr_row").addClass('sbr_row_act');

sb_url = $(on_a).attr('href');
```

How does the above differ from this?

```
$("#sb_results > a:first .sbr_row").addClass('sbr_row_act');

sb_url = $("#sb_results > a:first").attr('href');
```

Last one does work but not the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `on_a` is a jQuery object, you're concatenating its `toString` representation, which would end up looking like this:

```
"[object Object] .sbr_row"
```

What you want is:

```
on_a = $("#sb_results > a:first");
on_a.find(".sbr_row").addClass('sbr_row_act');
```

...which is the same as:

```
$("#sb_results > a:first .sbr_row").addClass('sbr_row_act');
```

The space in the selector between `a:first` and `.sbr_row` is the [`descendant-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), which is effectively the same as using the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you are assigning a jquery **object** to **on_a** and then using it in string concatenation.

```
on_a = $("#sb_results > a:first");
$(on_a + " .sbr_row").addClass('sbr_row_act'); //here on_a is a jquery object not the string "#sb_results > a:first"
```

If you change it to following it would be logically same as the second version:

```
on_a = $("#sb_results > a:first");
$(".sbr_row", on_a).addClass('sbr_row_act'); // or on_a.find(".sbr_row").addClass('sbr_row_act');
```